# Linq-to-SQL commit changes to DB but mdf file is empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, linq-to-sql

I have an `mdf` file and `dbml` attached.

I'm trying to insert and query the db using linq-to-sql.

I have the following code:

```
    var db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var s1 = db.Students.Where(s => s.Name == "gogo");
```

this code shows 0 results when running, but after executing the following

```
    var db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    Student newStudent = new Student { Name = "gogo" };
    db.Students.InsertOnSubmit(newStudent);
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

I can then get 1 relevant result.

The problem is when I open the `mdf` file he looks empty (even though I can query for a student named Adam with I added earlier).

My connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: You mean this is not saved in DB ?

Comment: show your connection string. Could be that you add it to different db

Comment: basically visual-studio copy a new local database in every time you generate your code (this is a new VS strategy started with VS 2012) for earlier version VS copy the database when you modify the code) so if you added a new something to your database from your code that means you will have till next time you generate your code.

Comment: @MairajAhmad actually I think that is it saved in the DB but does not shows in the DB.

Comment: @BadroNiaimi I excecuted the code several times but the DB doesn't show any of the changes (even though I can query and get the real data).

Comment: The point of @Badro is that in your project directory you have an empty database file, which gets copied to `bin` on build. Your program writes to the one in `bin`, and you're looking at the empty one in your project directory.

Comment: so where can I see the actual mdf file? 
or how can I make visual keep only 1 copy of mdf file

Comment: indeed you have one `mdf` file in the project directory, this `mdf` will be copied to your bin directory (release or debug depending on you compilation mode) the main database is the `mdf` in the main directory VS will copy this one to your bin directory every time you compile the project, so the modification on the other `mdf` will be removed.

Comment: @BadroNiaimi ok based on your answer I checked bin folder and saw that bin folder contains another mdf file and in this mdf file I can see the updates! but in the main mdf that in the solution I see no lines as if it was empty.. what could be the problem?

Comment: @Jynxed there is no problem, this is as I said is a VS way to generate projects, so if you want to add some lines to you main `mdf` file you should add them from VS server explorer, but you don't have to, because when you finish your project you will use only the release folder, so you will use one `mdf` file, 
But you can see this topic [how to exclude files from the Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms171455.aspx)